# Bundle a folder with a .Net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

How can I bundle a folder with a one click application and reference those files/folders after?

Seems rather simple but I just can't figure out how.

As in, I had the file `index.html` in the folder `UI` and I wanted to package that with the application, then I want to get the stream for that file with the string `"/UI/index.html"` but instead of just `index.html`, an entire website.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by 'reference those files/folders after'? I also don't see where the website in the title ties in. Some more detail about what you are trying to do will surely help.

Comment: Updated. I just want to bundle a folder with the application where I can use the files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the folder to your VS Project, right-click on it and select "embed as resource". That will make the files in the folder be embedded in the .NET assembly. To get the file contents in your program, you can use something like this:

```
public class ReadResource
{
    public string ReadInEmbeddedFile (string filename) {
        // assuming this class is in the same assembly as the resource folder
        var assembly = typeof(ReadResource).Assembly;

        // get the list of all embedded files as string array
        string[] res = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames ();

        var file = res.Where (r => r.EndsWith(filename)).FirstOrDefault ();

        var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream (file);
        string file_content = new StreamReader(stream).ReadToEnd ();

        return file_content;
     }
}
```

In the above function I assume your files a text/html files; if not, you can change it not to return string but byte[], and use a binary stream reader for that.
I also select the files by `file.EndsWith()` which is enough for my needs; if your folder has a deep nested structure you need to modify that code to parse for folder levels.

Comment: There will be at least two levels the base and levels like `js` or `css` or folders like that. Code help for that?

Comment: If you are providing website data through http requests, I think you already got the path somehow. So if a user requests /js/myscript.js or /css/site.css, pass this relative path to the above function, it will work (because `Yourproject/UI/css/site.css` actually ends with `/css/site.css`. Best is you take a look with the debugger to the `res` variable. It contains your folder structure, but prefixed with the location of the files in your namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps there is a better way, but given the content is not too large you can embed binaries directly into your program as a base64 string. In this case it would need to be an archive of the folder. You would also need to embed the dll used for unzipping that archive (If I understood correctly you want to have single .exe and nothing more).

Here is a short example

```
// create base64 strings prior to deployment
string unzipDll = Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes("Ionic.Zip.dll"));
string archive = Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes("archive.zip"));
```

---

```
string unzipDll = "base64string";
string archive = "probablyaverylongbase64string";

File.WriteAllBytes("Ionic.zip.dll", Convert.FromBase64String(unzipDll));
File.WriteAllBytes("archive.zip", Convert.FromBase64String(archive);

Ionic.Zip.ZipFile archive = new Ionic.Zip.ZipFile(archiveFile);
archive.ExtractAll("/destination");
```

---

The unzipping library is DotNetZip. It's nice because you need just a single dll. http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/downloads/get/258012

Edit:
Come to think of it, as long as you write the Ionic.dll to the working directory of the .exe you shouldn't need to use the dynamic dll loading so I removed that part to simplify the answer (it would still need to be written before you reach the method it is in though).

Comment: Why would you embed binaries as base64?

Comment: This allows you to store the data directly in your program as a simple string which you can then convert back into the raw bytes when you need it.

Comment: The simpler way is above :P

Comment: yeah, I figured there was a better way to do it, but since on one had answered yet I thought I'd give you a solution to chew on :)